# how can i turn a text file of results into a cleaned up version text file using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, automation

Does anyone know how could i to write a shell script that reads in a text file (i.e.`tests.txt`) as an input and then process it and saves the results on another file (i.e.`cleantabletests.txt`)

*for example:*

**input** `tests.txt` contains the following:

```
your test with name="firstTest" has finished succesfully but results="failed"
your test with name="secondTest" has finished successfully but results="passed"
your test with name="thirdTest" has finished successfully but results="passed"
```

**process**: use a shell script to read the `tests.txt` and process it to output the results in this `cleantabletests.txt`

**output** after `tests.txt` was processed `cleantabletests.txt` should look like this:

```
1, name="firstTest", results="failed"
2, name="secondTest", results="passed"
3, name="thirdTest", results="passed"
```

i am only interested in the names and results to use them to create a table afterwards

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: ...so, f/e, if you showed code that demonstrated that you already knew about and were trying to use the techniques taught by the linked duplicates, but were having a problem in applying those techniques, that would allow an answer distinct from the ones already given on those preexisting questions, because it would make your question more distinct and narrow.

Comment: the issue is i am not very well versed in bash scripting and what i am trying to do is this:
**[i=0] ;
for every line do {
 if [name=[.]* && result=[.]*] {
  NAME="name=[.]*" && RESULT="result=[.]*" && NUMBER=i;
  echo NUMBER NAME RESULT >> cleantablestests.txt;
  i++;}}
if no more lines [quit]**

sorry for my crude syntax